# PHP Columns and Rows with Pagination

Tags: php

I currently use a responsive grid framework for my html sites and now I need to incorporate fetching results from a database to populate the rows/columns.

Im looking to do 4 columns x 3 rows setting data horizontally.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
   <div class="three columns">$row=>result</div>
</div>
```

Any clue as to how I would set this up with a counter? As well as pagination?

Comment: did you try jQuery or something else to do it?

Comment: I am doing a SELECT FROM sql statement to pull the data rows, I cant figure out how to put them in rows and columns rather then 1 column. I have searched for plugins but all I found is plugins to deal with tabular data.

Comment: But this seems to be tabular data, so why don't you use a table?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [JQuery for pagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)

or if you want to use php, make it so you site url look something like this

```
http://mysite.com/&page=2
```

then in your query you will show 5 rows per page.
FOR PAGE 1

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE `bla bla` LIMIT 0,5
```

FOR PAGE 2

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE `bla bla` LIMIT 5,5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically have your heart set on using those DIV's, then I would use "tablesorter" and JQuery.  The tablesorter has a pagination module, so can do everything you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to use the DIV's. Like I said above I am using a Responsive Grid Framework so the site is laid out correctly on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I added some navigation

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).prop("href").replace(/.*#/,"");
        // or (maybe faster and better)
        // var page = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
        // or even (what is the same)
        // var page = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
        $('.row').hide().eq(parseInt(page)-1).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

view [the **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/vNEs7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $n_qry = "SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM TABLE_NAME";
    $n_res = mysql_query($n_qry) or die(mysql_error());
    $n_row = mysql_fetch_object($n_res);
    $total_cnt = $n_row->cnt;?>
    <ul><?php
    for($i=1;$i<=$total_cnt;$i=i+5)
    { ?>
        <li><a href="about.html?page=<?=$i;?>"><?=$i;?></a></li> | 
    <? } ?>
    </ul>
if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page']!='')
          {
              $iqry="SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id =".$id." LIMIT ".($_REQUEST['page']).",($_REQUEST['page']+5)";
          }
          else
          {
              $iqry="SELECT * FROM inner_page WHERE page_id =".$page_id." LIMIT 0,5";
          }
            $fiqry = mysql_query($iqry) or die(mysql_error());
            $rowi = mysql_fetch_object($fiqry);

            echo stripslashes($rowi->FIELD_NAME);
```

I used it for pagination for my site i hope it'll work for you. :)